# Is it possible to swim back to land if you fall in the clouds?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Several times now I have fallen into the clouds around the first main city, but the only way I can seem to get out is to Skip Travel. Is this a recurring theme? Or will some places offer me the ability to get out without Skip Traveling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to reach land when Cloud Sea level is raised, and only in several places.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like that's another mechanism for exploration then.

Answer (score 3):

To be specific, you can swim in the Cloud Sea at the following places:

- Argentum (Everywhere)
- Gormott (High Tide)
- Mor Ardain (High Tide)
- > Leftherian Archipelago (Everywhere)
- > Temperantia (At the certain points, such as the coast at the south of the central plain. You can only swim out so far before being returned to shore
- > Cliffs of Morytha (At the start of the area where the Nopon Merchants are. Again, only so far out.)